# 64-bit Program - Windows "Shadow Space" Trouble

Tags: windows, assembly, stack, x86-64, shadow

I am trying to create a program in x64 assembly language but I am having problems understanding the x64 calling convention. I believe that the problem is that I do not know how much shadow space I have to reserve for the call to the CopyFile function. When, I run the program, it just crashes. I created this program using MASM. Please help me fix this code. Thank you.

```
includelib \Masm64\Lib\Kernel32.lib
includelib \Masm64\Lib\User32.lib
extrn GetProcessHeap : proc
extrn MessageBoxA : proc
extrn HeapAlloc : proc
extrn GetModuleFileNameA : proc
extrn ExitProcess : proc
extrn CopyFileA : proc

dseg segment para 'DATA'
file db 'C:\CopyThisFile.txt', 0
file2 db 'C:\ThisFileWasCopied.txt', 0
succ db 'Success!', 0
capt db 'Debug', 0
dseg ends

cseg segment para 'CODE'
start proc
sub rsp, 28h
xor r8, r8
mov rdx, qword ptr file2
mov rcx, qword ptr file
call CopyFileA
xor ecx, ecx 
call ExitProcess
start endp
cseg ends
end
```

Comment: Why not write and compile a simple C program and see what it does?

Comment: I don't know much about C, but I know about 3rd-generation languages. It is because I want to learn about the low-level languages first, and work my way up, to higher-level languages.

Comment: `mov rdx, qword ptr file2` loads rdx with the contents of `file2`. I think you want `offset` there. Same with `rcx`.

Comment: Thanks, but am also curious what RSP is after the call. What does it mean when its the caller's responsibility to clean the stack?

Comment: Not much call for pure assembler devs anymore.  You should really take a bit of time and learn some C.  It will help with your assembler as well having some C framework in your mind.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, because, assembly language is still around. It is an active topic in some assembly language forums. It is also required for some majors in college. Finally, it is inevitable for antivirus programs to avoid assembly language. Also, I already know how to program in C++ and Java, but I only want to learn assembly right now.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with space reservation on the stack.

Your mistake instead lies in getting the string's address incorrectly. `mov` gets the contents (first 8 bytes) instead of the pointer to the string, hence raises a AccessViolation exception. To fix this, use `lea`.

```
format PE64 GUI 5.0
entry start

include 'WIN64A.INC'

section '.data' data readable writeable

    fileStr db 'C:\\CopyThisFile.txt', 0
    file2Str db 'C:\\ThisFileWasCopied.txt', 0
    succ db 'Success!', 0

section '.text' code readable executable

    start:

    sub rsp, 28
    xor r8, r8
    lea rdx, qword ptr file2Str
    lea rcx, qword ptr fileStr
    call [CopyFileA]
    xor ecx, ecx
    call [ExitProcess]

section '.idata' import data readable

    library kernel32,'kernel32.dll',user32,'user32.dll'

    import kernel32, \
        GetProcessHeap,'GetProcessHeap', \
        HeapAlloc,'HeapAlloc', \
        GetModuleFileNameA,'GetModuleFileNameA', \
        ExitProcess,'ExitProcess', \
        CopyFileA,'CopyFileA'

    import user32, \
        MessageBoxA,'MessageBoxA'
```

Comment: You definitely *should* reserve shadow space for ANY function you call as per Win64 ABI - the OP had that notion right. The assembler won't do that for you. (And the observation that something seemingly works can be misleading.)

Comment: A little late on the answer--the program was fixed long ago... However, I am curious on what "qword ptr" actually does. Any help?

Comment: It's a pointer to some memory, and the address is 64 bits, hence 'qword'

Comment: I know that, of course, but why does the push instruction associated with qword ptr fiasco push the contents of file2 instead of pushing the pointer itself? I dunno. I'm a little confused with MASM semantics.

Comment: I've programmed a while in assembly languages on windows and I've experienced that the shadow space isn't the same for all windows functions. example calling a messagebox often works with no stackspace. also PostQuitMessage except in subroutines, there I need 8 byes shadow space. The ShellAboutA function needs 30h (48 bytes) of shadow space or it crashes all the time.
Does anybody know how to know the right shadowspace for each function ?
(All were called in separate subroutines)